# How to get length of String in flutter and display in firestore array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create an array of information into firestore and I want to achieve this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
Future uploadData(String name) async {
    List<String> splitList = name.split('');
    List<String> indexList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++){
      for (int y = 1 ; y < splitList[i].length + 1; y++) {
        indexList.add(splitList[i].substring(0,y).toLowerCase());
      }
      name = name + name[i];
      indexList.add(name);
    }
    print(indexList);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).update({
      'arrayUser': indexList
    });
  }
```

but it crash the application...

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Without that, it's hard to say more than https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#writing-data

Answer (score 1):

Hi have found a way to achieve what I needed.
Hope that can help the community:

```
Future nameArray(String name) async {
List<String> arrName = [];
String s = name.toLowerCase();
String e = '';
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  e = e + s[i];
  arrName.add(e);
}

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).update({
  'userArray': FieldValue.arrayUnion(arrName)
});
```